# How to run a specific function in Python file via R in Shiny?

Tags: python, r, shiny, shiny-server, reticulate

I'm using `source_python()` function to run a Python Script via user interface of R Shiny. Code is running properly and I'm successful in it. But I want to run a function named `function2()` which is in `Task3.py`. Can I do this? If yes then how can I do this? I just want to execute `function2()`. I don't want `function1()` and `function3()` to run. I'm doing this by using following lines and syntax which I found by Googling. I'm unsuccessful in running just `function2()` by following below link. The link that I followed is:

> https://rstudio.github.io/reticulate/articles/calling_python.html

***server.R:***

```
library(reticulate)
observeEvent(input$action,{
    py_run_file("applications/Task3.py")
    function2()
  })
```

***Task3.py:***

```
def main(argv):
   function1()
   ....
   function2()
   ....
   function3()
   ....
if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        k=sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
    except (ValueError, IOError) as e:
        sys.exit(e)
```

Comment: The first example in the linked tutorial does exactly what you want. Just import your module instead of OS.

Answer (score 2):

To call a single function from a python module, you need to import the module as an object and run the function from it rather than executing the module as a script.

The tutorial you linked starts with how to do exactly that. Instead of `py_run_file`, you'll want to use `import`:

```
library(reticulate)
observeEvent(input$action,{
    task3 <- import("Task3")
    task3$function2()
})
```

You may have to switch to the `applications` directory or add it to your PYTHONPATH for the import to work properly.

Comment: Sir, I'm getting this error by doing this:
`Warning: Error in py_get_attr_impl: AttributeError: module 'Task3' has no attribute 'function2()'`

Comment: That's because you don't define or import `function2` in your module. You need to fix your python code.

Comment: Is it possible also to pass parameters to the function call ?

Comment: @Angelo. I would assume so. I've never actually used R :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `source_python()` instead of `py_run_file`. This will add a function to your `.Globalenv` which the python function in `task3.py`.

```
library(reticulate)
observeEvent(input$action,{
    source_python("task3.py")
    function2()
})
```